# Powershell: automated process to copy files and compare hash

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a job to do that requires me to create an automated process where I am to

1. FolderA files---- `Get-Filehash -algorithm MD5 > c:\test\Axxx.txt`
2. copy files from FolderA to FolderB
3. FolderB files---- `Get-Filehash -algorithm MD5 > c:\test\Bxxx.txt`
4. compare the differences of the hash in both text files(same location)
5. No difference, operation completed
6. Yes difference, popup to show difference

I am stuck with all the cmdlets..it's too difficult to uds! but I am still trying to learn PS.

Comment: We are a community to help programmers and programming enthusiasts. That being said, it is expect that you show what you have done or tried before posting. This gives us something to build on. As of now this reads like a code writing request which is off topic for SO. Break your question into its parts and search individually for solutions to those problems. Then, if you are still having issues, please [edit] your question showing your work so we can better help you and the community.

Comment: i dont andeerstand you ask. If you copy your files into FolderB then Hash dont change, your comparaison have never difference. What do you try to do?

Comment: I'm sorry, i will take note of all these, thanks Matt

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way of achieving what you want.

```
$folderA = "c:\tmp"
$folderB = "c:\tmp2"
$hashA = "c:\hashofA.txt"
$hashB = "c:\hashofB.txt"

Get-ChildItem $folderA -Recurse -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | Select  -ExpandProperty Hash >> $hashA

Get-ChildItem $folderA -Recurse | foreach{ Copy-Item $_.FullName $folderB}

Get-ChildItem $folderB -Recurse  -File | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | Select -ExpandProperty Hash >> $hashB


$a = Get-Content $hashA
$b = Get-Content $hashB

if(Compare-Object $a $b)
{"Files are different"}
else{"Files are same"}
```

Comment: your last Get-ChildItem should be $folderB Junaid. Note: you can do gci -recurse -File instead of "Where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}" ;)

Comment: hmm thanks mate. :) i didn't know i can do -File. I have fixed the answer.

Comment: I have edited the code now as the previous one wasn't working properly. You need to use Compare-Objects for text files.

Comment: Hi Junaid, Thank you for the help! I managed to get the hang of the cmds and i will try it out myself and update again